# mount --no-canonicalize?

Tags: linux, security, mount, options, fuse

Neither `man` nor `info` page provide more information on this than:

> `mount --no-canonicalize` Don't canonicalize paths. The mount  command  canonicalizes  all paths  (from  command  line  or  fstab) and stores canonicalized paths to the /etc/mtab file. This option can  be  used  together with the -f flag for already canonicalized absolut paths.

In connection with `fuse`, I found that it was introduced to Linux Kernel 2.8.5 to prevent *… local users to bypass intended access restrictions and unmount arbitrary directories via a symlink attack* [→ [source](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2011-0543)].

**Question**: What is `mount --no-canonicalize` actually used for? Was this just a security issue or what else is this option used for?

As I'm quite limited in my settings here, I was just able to mount USB Flash Drives with and without this option, with the exact same output in `/etc/mtab` and when using `mount --show-labels`in the minutest detail. This might be different with other file systems.

**Update 1**: `umount` also provides this option, where both `man` and `info` page tells one

> `--no-canonicalize` Don't canonicalize paths. *For more details about this option see the mount(8) man page*

Answer (score 1):

The canonicalization refers to the device path.  So you say:

> I was just able to mount USB Flash Drives with and without this option, with the exact same output in /etc/mtab

But did you try this?

```
cd /dev
mount --no-canonicalize sdb1 /mnt/usb
```

The listing in `mtab` will start with just "sdb1".  Without `--no-canonicalize`, it would be /dev/sdb1.  Also:

```
ln -s /dev/sdb1 ~/mydev
cd ~
mount --no-canonicalize mydev /mnt/usb
```

The mtab listing will be for "mydev", whereas without --no-canonicalize it will be for /dev/sdb1.

Not sure what that has to do with unmounting via a symlink attack on unprivilleged mounts, but it does allow for obscuring paths in the publicly accessible `/etc/mtab`.  It is hard to symlink something if you don't have a canonical (or any) path for it.

Comment: As logically and good as it sounds, it doesn't work for me. I get the same results with[out] `no-canonicalize`